# When dojo.js loaded via ajax multiple times get Error: defineAlreadyDefined

Tags: jquery, ajax, dojo

I use jquery to load in sub-pages via ajax. The sub-page has some dojo widgets which work ok the first time. But subsequent loads I get Error: defineAlreadyDefined and the rest of the javascripts after this point is not run which means some key jquery instructions, e.g. UI layout.
Can any one help as I have searched the web for this "Error: defineAlreadyDefined" of dojo and the best I came up with was it was addressed in dojo 1.6, however I am using 1.7.2 . I hope that I am doing something stupid as it is very frustrating as you would expect that dojo.js could be loaded many times by the user performing refresh etc. I should add that I tried placing the dojo.js in the main html page but then I received problems of dijit not found when loading the sub-page.

Comment: It's weird to use both JQuery and dojo in the same app... why don't you add prototype and motools on top ? it might help ! ;-) Try placing dojo.js as well as the declaration of all your dijits in the main page. Also if you can, get rid of one of the 2 frameworks.

Comment: Its a fairly extensive app and many modules have been written using jQuery as base. But I found Dojo offerred more for field, text editor, and grid. Most of my inquiries of jQuery and Dojo coexistence was positive, so I thought I would progress in that direction. Other than the above issue it was happening for me. Ignoring additional memory etc. I just don't see why I cannot work around it.

Comment: The thing is that your error is pretty generic. It just means that you are redefining objects that are already in the registry. What do you use for UI layout ? It looks like reloading your panels does not destroy the inner objects properly. Can you try to replace your UI layout components by those in dijit.layout or is it too much work ?

Comment: I use the jquery UI layout on all pages, well more like this:- there is one html page with a header, footer, left, right, and centre panes. When a page is selected from the menu I have a jscript which performs an ajax call for the centre pane and maybe (depending on the page) an ajax call to load left and/or right panes. The header and footer tend to be stable. For each pane to be loaded via ajax a destroy is performed first. if(typeof(innerCenterLayout) != "undefined") innerCenterLayout.destroy();  $(".ui-layout-center").html("");

Comment: First time to load the dojo in centre pane, hiding left and right panes, it works fine. I load in another non-dojo page to the centre pane which is fine, then when I go back to reload the dojo page again I get the error.

Comment: To drop the jquery ui layout to go to dojo layout would be a fair amount of work because of the page contents and I am not too sure if, after that work, everytyhing would be ok. At this stage jquery is everywhere where dojo is only on this one page for testing. I do take your point of the generic and I do perform dijit.registry.forEach(function(w){ w.destroy() as well as the jquery destroy.

Answer (score 0):

I could not resolve the actual error message and I believe its cause is buried within dojo initial load on a reload. However, to resolve the realigning of ui-layout panes I included `myLayout.initContent("center")​` in the ajax onComplete function.

Answer (score 0):

dojo.js defines a global variable called `define`. I'm fairly certain the error you're seeing comes from if you load dojo.js more than once and its to let you know that `define` is already defined.  Ideally you should just load dojo.js once.

Comment: Thanks, I certainly missed that one as I interpret define as a message and not the name of a variable. Yes I am multi loading as it is coming in via an ajax call and I can not alter this approach at this point because of the dijits being used.